# Acceptance test failed when js enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am having a weird problem with my acceptance test for login page.

The login works fine when js in not enabled ie. the following case:

```
  scenario "login with valid authentication" do
    visit login_path
    page.should have_content("Sprout Login")
    fill_in("user_login", :with => "mark")
    fill_in("user_password", :with => "secured")
    click_button "Sign in"
    page.should have_content("mark")
  end
```

But when I enabled javascript, the login fails and gives invalid login message.

```
  scenario "login with valid authentication", :js => true do
    visit login_path
    page.should have_content("Sprout Login")
    fill_in("user_login", :with => "mark")
    fill_in("user_password", :with => "secured")
    click_button "Sign in"
    page.should have_content("mark")
  end
```

BTW I am using Devise for authentication. 
Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE: recently noticed that when js is enabled, test server is not starting and hence login fails. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your tests will fail unless a default user is created and logs in before each test runs. Devise provides test helpers to make it simple to create and log in a default user. Create a file spec/support/devise.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: Nope, I guess the problem is with starting test server. When I fire up the test, I guess it had to automatically start the test server but it does not. I have to manually start the server `rails -s -e test' and then do test again and it works. The confusion is that why does this happens only when js is enabled. :S

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found [a thread with a solution](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/97bfecbcf9c242dc?pli=1):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

For the DatabaseCleaner stuff to work you'll need to include the `database_cleaner` gem. If you haven't used it before, you may need to `rake db:test:prepare` before rerunning your tests. I hope this works for you, too!